# Separating logs with filter in log4net only works for one value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net

I've got an ASP.NET MVC application using log4net on a Windows Server 2008 R2 and Window Server 2012. The application is installed as two separate instances with common code base, ie the log4net configuration file will be the same in both folder but I want to separate the logging to two different files depending on the hostname of the called web site.

I've tried setting up two different appenders with a property filter to filter out a value I set as seen below:

```
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["site"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```

The filter for each appender in my log4net configuration file looks like this:

```
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <key value="site" />
      <StringToMatch value="hostnameA" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

The two web sites only share the common code, but have separate installation folders and separate application pools. Still only the web sites started first gets a working logger, the second doesn't log at all. If I IISRESET and then start web site B first and web site A second, then web site B (the first) works but not web site A.

I've tried both GlobalContext, ThreadContext and LogicalThreadContext, all with the same result. I've tried log4net 1.12.11 and 1.12.12.

Any tips?

Jonas

Answer (score 0):

since you have two appenders logging into same file, one app will acquire a write lock on both and the other will fail.

My solution would be to add %processid to the log file name. That way, each process will always have it's own file at a given time - no conflicts. Try like this:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="log-file-[%processid].txt" />
```

See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.PatternString.html